# OpenIso8583.Net Adding a bit to the template

Tags: iso8583, openiso8583.net

The library was moved some years ago and the link I found for a wiki is stale.

I would like to add bit 127 to the Iso8583 class. I am using the below code but the program dies in the Pack() method, called from ToMsg(). I don't know what value to put in the length field. The field is a LLLVAR with a max length of 5, so is the length 5, or 8, or 999? All three values throw an exception in Pack().

What do I need to add to get bit 127 working?

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenIso8583Net;
using OpenIso8583Net.FieldValidator;
using OpenIso8583Net.Formatter;
using OpenIso8583Net.LengthFormatters;

namespace MyLink
{

    public class MyIso8583 : Iso8583
    {
        public new class Bit : Iso8583.Bit
        {    
            public const int _127_DISCOVER_VERSION = 127;
        }

        // First you need to customise the template
        // The message 
        private static readonly Template template;


        static MyIso8583()
        {

            // Get the default template for the Iso8583 class
            template = GetDefaultIso8583Template();

            // change template to add bit 127 LLLVAR(5)

            template.Add(Bit._127_DISCOVER_VERSION, FieldDescriptor.AsciiVar(3, 5, FieldValidators.AlphaNumericSpecial));

        }

        // override the base class using the template 
        public MyIso8583() : base(template)
        {

        }

        protected override IField CreateField(int field)
        {

            return base.CreateField(field);
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT 3/24/20: I added an override to Bit and CreateField. I want the new bit 127 to act like a default LLLVAR of length 5.

Answer (score 0):

This code works. It may not actually be necessary to add the CreateField override.